# Wave Signal Process (Period)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, numerical-methods, frequency-analysis

What is the best way to detect 1 period in a wave signal?

Does somebody have a specific algorithm to do that? And do you know where you found it?

I know fft, but I don't know how make it give me the wave period (position at time).

Split the signal in periods!

I'd like pascal, matlab...

Comment: By detect 1 period, do you mean the length of a period, or where in phase the signal is at some point in time?

Comment: You've asked no real question, and your tags are meaningless; they have no commonality whatsoever. Did you just randomly select them?

Comment: What is it you actually want? Do you want to detect the phase of a frequency at a certain point in time? The amplitude? Do you want to find the most dominant frequency in a signal? FFT can be used for any of these, but you have to actually know what it is that you are looking for. What do you mean by position in time? This has no meaning when talking about a wave period.

Comment: This is a difficult question. Does your signal have specific properties ?

Comment: wave, wave frequency, wavelength and period. Split the signal in periods! I want to detect the period at a certain point in time!

Comment: The algorithm is Pitchmarker, search the algorithm in matlab

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not at all the best way, but one way that can work to find the
period of a periodic signal is to [unwrap
the](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unwrap.html)
[phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase). Here is Matlab
(actually Octave) code:

```
t = linspace(0, 20, 50);
sig = sin(t) + rand(size(t))*0.2;

% Hilbert transform to give an analytic signal.
% The complex argument will
% now be the instantaneous phase.
n = length(sig);
m = n/2+1;
U = fft(sig) / length(sig);
U((m+1):n) = 0;
cpx = ifft(U);

% Get the phase.
phase = arg(cpx);

% Unwrap the phase.
for i = 2:length(phase)
    k = round((phase(i) - phase(i-1))/(2*pi));
    phase(i) = phase(i) - k*2*pi;
end

% Fit a linear model.
lin_est = [t', repmat(1, length(t), 1)] \ phase';

% The frequency is the rate of change of the phase over time.
freq_est = lin_est(1)/2/pi
T_est = 1 / freq_est
```

Other thingns to look at [acf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation),
[fft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis).

Comment: The algorithm is Pitchmarker, search the algorithm in matlab